# JPA projection with custom resulting field names

Tags: java, jpa

I use interface-based projections using named-native-query. My UserDTO looks like this:

```
public interface UserDTO {

@Value("#{target.USER_ID}")
String getId();
@Value("#{target.USER_NAME}")
String getName();
@Value("#{target.REGISTRATION_REGION}")
String getRegistrationRegion();

}
```

After that I marshall the list of DTOs to Json, and field names which I see there are in camel-case:

```
    {"USERS": [
        {
            "id": "e00000099232200",
            "name": 1616674065,
            "registrationRegion": 1617344002
        }]}
```

But I need them in DB style - Upper-case and with underscores like:

```
{"USERS": [
        {
            "ID": "e00000099232200",
            "NAME": 1616674065,
            "REGISTRATION_REGION": 1617344002
        }]}
```

The straightforward way is naming my DTOs methods like `getNAME` or `getREGISTRATION_REGION` or iterating over Json fields and make them upper-case there. But is there a more elegant way to set the display name? Something like this:

```
@Display("REGISTRATION_REGION")
String getRegistrationRegion();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Jackson you can annotate your interface with:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
```

Or if you want this behaviour globally across all usages of your mapper, configure it as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy());
```

EDIT:
You can implement your own CaseStrategy, for your case it will be:

```
    class UpperSnakeCase extends PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy{
        @Override
        public String translate(String input) {
            String snakeCased = super.translate(input);
            if (snakeCased == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return  snakeCased.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is just "UpperCamelCase" but not CAMEL_CASE

Comment: Sorry, for behaviour you want you can take SnakeCaseStrategy and wrap ip with .toUpperCase() as in updated answer.